# Completion Block AFNetworking in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm working on an iOS app whose the basis is Objective-C with AFNetworking for communicate with the API. Now I'm writing my new ViewControllers in Swift and have some problems with the CompletionBlock in the Swift files.

The original Objective-C code:

```
- (void)downloadJson {
    [[ODDWebService sharedInstance] getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *result, BOOL succes) {
        if(succes) {
            [self.parkings removeAllObjects];

            for(NSDictionary *dict in result) {
                Parking *parking = [[Parking alloc] init];
                parking.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
                parking.freespace = [[dict objectForKey:@"freespace"] integerValue];
                [self.parkings addObject:parking];
            }
            [self updateParkings];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR RETRIEVING PARKING SPACES");
        }
    }];
}
```

This is what I thought it should be in Swift:

```
func downloadJson() {
    ODDWebService.sharedInstance().getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock { (result: AnyObject, succes: Bool) -> Void in
        if(succes) {
            self.parkings.removeAllObjects()

            for dict: NSDictionary in result {
                var parking: Parking = Parking
                parking.name = dict["name"]
                parking.freespace = dict["freespace"].integerValue()
                parkings.addObject(parking)
            } else {
                NSLog("ERROR RETRIEVING PARKING SPACES")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main error is found in the second line of code:

```
'(AnyObject, Bool) -> Void' is not convertible to '(([AnyObject]!, Bool) -> Void)!'
```

Comment: simply add "!" after anyobject ODDWebService.sharedInstance().getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock { (result: AnyObject!, succes: Bool) -> Void in

Comment: When I do this, the error(s) in the ViewController disappear, but I get an Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
func downloadJson() {
ODDWebService.sharedInstance().getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock { (result: AnyObject, succes: Bool) -> Void in
    if(succes) {
```

With

```
func downloadJson() {
ODDWebService.sharedInstance().getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock {
result, success  in
    if(succes) {
```

Also add the first line in the following code to your code.

```
if let dicts = result as? NSDictionary<String, AnyObject> {
for dict: NSDictionary in dicts {
            var parking: Parking = Parking
            parking.name = dict["name"]
```

Comment: This resolves also the first problem, but `for dict: NSDictionary in result {` line gives still the error `'[AnyObject]!' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'`

Comment: I got now a new warning on if let dicts line: `Cast from '[AnyObject]!' to unrelated type '[String : AnyObject]' always fails` And an error on the for dict line: `'[String : AnyObject]' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'`

Comment: Now the warning is: `Cast from '[AnyObject]!' to unrelated type 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' always fails` and the error is now: `'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'`

Comment: Still not working :(, the warning is still the same and there are now 2 errors: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSDictionary'` and `'Element' (aka '(key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject)') is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast NSArray to Anyobject. Can you try this code:

```
func downloadJson() {
    ODDWebService.sharedInstance().getParkingSpacesWithCompletionBlock { (result: [AnyObject]!, success: Bool) -> Void in
        if(succes) {
            self.parkings.removeAllObjects()

            for dict in result as NSArray {
                var parking: Parking = Parking
                parking.name = dict["name"]
                parking.freespace = dict["freespace"].integerValue()
                parkings.addObject(parking)
            } else {
                NSLog("ERROR RETRIEVING PARKING SPACES")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great this solves the first problem, but now I get the message:
`'[AnyObject]!' is not convertible to 'NSDictionary'`